# Set a session when page is loaded

Tags: 7, forms

I want to define a session in contributed module (field collection module) in drupal 7 when the page is loaded.

This session takes a value from the URL and fill one of the field that depend on it. I defined a session in the form_alter function but I need to refresh the page to let the session take the value? So, could anyone tell me where I can define it? In which function of the module?

Comment: `In which function of the module?` see [How to run check on each page load?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33789/how-to-run-check-on-each-page-load)

Comment: in field_collection_form_alter function.

Comment: I checked the link that you post it. The suggest to use MYMODULE_boot() 
function. I try to use it but without any success. I think I cannot use this function in contributed module.

Comment: which contrib module?

Comment: field collection module

Comment: What do you need the session for?

Comment: I need the session to take the node id and then I use this session to get the author of the node and  fill a field with the data that related to the author.

Comment: You don't need a session to do that.

Comment: The session is passed to the view and in the view it will do the contextual filtration depending on the session. So I need this session.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the session that Drupal creates. Just add your data to an element of the $_SESSION variable:

```
$_SESSION['my_module']['some_key'] = 'some value';
```

It will

Comment: I use this in field_collection_form_alter function but I need to refresh the page to set the session. In which function that I can use it to set the session when page is loaded?

Comment: You don't need to. Drupal already initiates the session.

Comment: Sorry.. But it which file I have to add this session. Does this work if I want to set the node id in the session when the user edit the node?

Comment: You can see it in hook _form_alter like you have already done.

Comment: The session is saved. But the session is set after the page is build. Is there a way to set the session when the page is loaded?

Comment: The session is initiated before page build. Why don't you tell us what you are trying to do, rather than how you are trying to do it.

Comment: I posted a question in this [link](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227656/the-data-in-unlimited-entity-reference-select-field-does-not-appear-after-adding) but unfortunately nobody help me or maybe nobody know how we can solve this issue. So, I tried to solve my issue by using another way. I tried to save the node id in a session then I pass it to the view. in contextual view i add this code in php code '$nidar=(int)$_SESSION['field_collection']['favcolor'];

$node = node_load($nidar);

$uid =  ($node->uid);

drupal_set_message('user id: '. $uid ,'warning');

return $uid;'

Comment: I added the session in form_alter function but I could not get the user id until I refresh the page once.